# protractor --page objects ,getting error Cannot read property 'click' of undefined. How to resolve this error?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

trying to access menu of an angular application from spec.js using page object menu.js but when running the protractor error is coming up. Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

```
spec.js

        var loginpage = require('./login');
        var Menu  = require('./menu');
        describe('todo', function() {
            it('activity', function() {

             var question = new loginpage();
            var menu = new Menu();
                    browser.sleep(10000);
                    menu.dropdown('Inquiry').click();

        });
        });


   PAGE OBJECT FILE menu.js


    var MenuPage = function() {
      this.dropdown = function(dropdownName) {

        var openDropdown = function() {
          element(by.css('.nav'))
              .element(by.css('[title=dropdownName]'))
              .click();
        };
     return {

          option: function(optionName) {
            openDropdown();
            return element(by.css('.dropdown.open'))
                .element(by.linkText(optionName));
          }
        }

      };
    };

    module.exports = MenuPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you have old style in your tests. It's much more easier to use new features of `JS`.

However, you return `object`. Instead of it return `element`. You can return function that will return element regarding to your code style:

```
return function(optionName) {
            openDropdown();
            return element(by.css('.dropdown.open'))
                .element(by.linkText(optionName));
          }
```